# Create PHP RegEx matching enumerating paragraphs

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm currently trying to create a regular expression for matching enumerations from law articles to apply some style-modifications for it.

Here is my current regex:

```
    /\R([0-9a-zA-Z])(\.|\))(.*?)(\R\R|$)/gs
```

https://regex101.com/r/WtT0cT/1

As you can see on regex101 the problem is with the sub-enumerations in enumeration number 3.

My regex doesn't need to also get each sub-enumeration but it should get all the text which belongs to this enumeration. This means for number 3 it should get the following:

> some text 3
>      More text in number 3
>
> a)  sub-enumeration a in 3
>
> b)  sub-enumeration b in 3
>
> c)  sub-enumeration c in 3
>
> d)  sub-enumeration d in 3
>
> Some text which belongs to no sub-enumeration but to enumeration 3

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
\h*[0-9a-zA-Z][.)][\s\S]+?(?=\R+\d|$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\h*         : 0 or more horizotal spaces
[0-9a-zA-Z] : 1 alphanumeric
[.)]        : dot or parenthesis
[\s\S]+?    : 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=         : lookahead
  \R+\d     : 1 or more linebreak, followed by a digit
  |         : OR
  $         : end of string
)            : end lookahead
```

[See in action](https://regex101.com/r/yTqEVS/1)